# Store in a variable or read from a file each time using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vb.net-2010

I am trying to deal with frequent checking of large amount of data in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET).

I need to check this large amount each time there are changes in the input of my application and that's also frequently.

Which of the following is smarter and faster?

1. *Read file at application start and fill all to variable collection?*

   **Application load:** `load the file` and then `for each line in file add to array mycollection` *(so file will be loaded only once)* 

   **Request to check:** `for each in mycollection if = Something then do stuff` *(for each request just check if have in collection)*

   - This seems faster to me, because I don't need to load all data at each request. But then the memory consumption of the application will be higher since the collection variable contains huge number of strings?!?
2. *Read file at each request?*

   **Request to check:** do the same as for 1, but each time it's requested. *(Read file on each request and compare)*

   - Lover memory usage, but slower if I am not wrong.

I'd like to avoid Microsoft [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server).

Are there any better ways?

Comment: How big is your file? It is always best to keep things in memory. You can try cache them, and have the cache cleared after some time.

Comment: well for a start it is small but if not found in collection then collection gets bigger :) hope this explains you all

Comment: It would help to know the order of magnitude at least. 1KB, 1MB, 1GB? Also please explain the nature of your collection and why it is growing. Could be that your solution lies in a better design.

Comment: checks and saves ip address of clients

Comment: Just so you know - the more you tell, the better your help will be. Proper analysis usually saves 90% of the time spent on coding.

Comment: i understand that... well its ip related so its ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what is contained in the file or how large it is, but assuming from your description that there is some logical division of data in the file, the way I would approach this problem is the following:

At startup, divide the file up into a number of smaller files based on the logical division of data within the file and named in a way that is correlated to the searches that you need to perform.

After you divide the file up, you can implement a rolling cache mechanism where you keep say 10 of the small files in memory and when you need information that is not cached, you remove the least used file and load the new one in.

This way you end up with a balance between memory usage and performance.

Comment: that i though also but what if there are 10,000 files or more? how will windows handle when i request for file? or if i split in folders and then inside folders 100 files per folder again same question will it make user windows(OS) slower while it search 1 file between 10K?

Comment: If you give the files or folders names that correlate to the data that they contain, then you can limit your file retrieval to a specific file or set of files. In this case, you wouldn't have to burden the OS with file names. Alternatively, you can keep an index of the file names in memory with information that can be used in searching. So, you would search the in-memory index first, then retrieve the specific file or files that contain the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you, at least for a try, a [NoSQL Database](http://nosql-database.org).

Wondering about your question, I believe a NoSQL database would give the best of both keeping your data recorded on disk and still having the performance (cache) and scalability.

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) is a good product to get started, including it's online shell you could give it a try.

Comment: i would prefer not to use any of third party things include their library's so on.